# Ramsay St Identification

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to find out how many streets across Australia are called 'Ramsay St'. How do I find out the unique number of streets called this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. We are a problem-solving site, not a tutorial one. Generally, Questions need to state what you have tried, and what problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 3):

[overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/) is a good way to query and extract openstreetmap data.

The following Query will find all Lines with the name like 'Ramsay St*' in Australia:

```
/*
FIND ALL WAYS AND RELATIONS WITH THE NAME: 'RAMSAY ST*'
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “name"
  (area["ISO3166-1:alpha2"="AU"];) ->.a;
  way["name"~"Ramsay St*"](area.a);
  rel["name"~"Ramsay St*"](area.a);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

That same query can be loaded and run from here:
**https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1hht**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Cushen. I'm receiving the below however when I try this. Do you know why?                                                                                                                                           An error occurred during the execution of the overpass query! This is what overpass API returned:
runtime error: Query timed out in "query" at line 9 after 27 seconds.

Comment: As the error suggests it is a time out issue. You can try editing the timeout parameter to something larger perhaps: [out:json][timeout:60];